# Contact Form 7 - File Types [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts, file-type

I want to make site visitors able to send me different, non-usual, file types. Like a PCB document, or a .psd file.
I've looked through all the code, didn't find any hint.
All I want is just to disable the file type check.
Also, I've read somewhere that it has something to do with the Wordpress config files, doesn't matter, I'll change them.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is listed on [the contact form 7 website](http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/).

The file types that are able to be uploaded are:

> Contact Form 7 applies default restrictions for file type and file size when you do not set the filetypes: and limit: (file size) options explicitly. Default acceptable file types (extensions) are: jpg, jpeg, png, gif, pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, odt, avi, ogg, m4a, mov, mp3, mp4, mpg, wav, and wmv. Default acceptable file size is 1 MB (1048576 bytes).

Answer (score -1):

```html
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
if (!is_plugin_active('contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php')) {
  return;
}

require_once ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php';

remove_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_file', 'wpcf7_file_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_file*', 'wpcf7_file_validation_filter', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_file', 'wpcf7_custom_file_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_file*', 'wpcf7_custom_file_validation_filter', 10, 2 );

function wpcf7_custom_file_validation_filter($result, $tag){
  $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

  $name = $tag->name;
  $id = $tag->get_id_option();

  $file = isset( $_FILES[$name] ) ? $_FILES[$name] : null;

  if ( $file['error'] && UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE != $file['error'] ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'upload_failed_php_error' ) );
    return $result;
  }

  if ( empty( $file['tmp_name'] ) && $tag->is_required() ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
    return $result;
  }

  if ( ! is_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] ) )
    return $result;

  $allowed_file_types = array();

  if ( $file_types_a = $tag->get_option( 'filetypes' ) ) {
    foreach ( $file_types_a as $file_types ) {
      $file_types = explode( '|', $file_types );

      foreach ( $file_types as $file_type ) {
        $file_type = trim( $file_type, '.' );
        $file_type = str_replace( array( '.', '+', '*', '?' ),
          array( '\.', '\+', '\*', '\?' ), $file_type );
        $allowed_file_types[] = $file_type;
      }
    }
  }

  $allowed_file_types = array_unique( $allowed_file_types );
  $file_type_pattern = implode( '|', $allowed_file_types );

  $allowed_size = 1048576; // default size 1 MB

  if ( $file_size_a = $tag->get_option( 'limit' ) ) {
    $limit_pattern = '/^([1-9][0-9]*)([kKmM]?[bB])?$/';

    foreach ( $file_size_a as $file_size ) {
      if ( preg_match( $limit_pattern, $file_size, $matches ) ) {
        $allowed_size = (int) $matches[1];

        if ( ! empty( $matches[2] ) ) {
          $kbmb = strtolower( $matches[2] );

          if ( 'kb' == $kbmb )
            $allowed_size *= 1024;
          elseif ( 'mb' == $kbmb )
            $allowed_size *= 1024 * 1024;
        }

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  /* File type validation */

  // Default file-type restriction
  if ( '' == $file_type_pattern )
    $file_type_pattern = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|odt|avi|ogg|m4a|mov|mp3|mp4|mpg|wav|wmv|ai|eps|tif';

  $file_type_pattern = trim( $file_type_pattern, '|' );
  $file_type_pattern = '(' . $file_type_pattern . ')';
  $file_type_pattern = '/\.' . $file_type_pattern . '$/i';

  if ( ! preg_match( $file_type_pattern, $file['name'] ) ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'upload_file_type_invalid' ) );
    return $result;
  }

  /* File size validation */

  if ( $file['size'] > $allowed_size ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'upload_file_too_large' ) );
    return $result;
  }

  wpcf7_init_uploads(); // Confirm upload dir
  $uploads_dir = wpcf7_upload_tmp_dir();
  $uploads_dir = wpcf7_maybe_add_random_dir( $uploads_dir );

  $filename = $file['name'];
  $filename = wpcf7_canonicalize( $filename );
  $filename = sanitize_file_name( $filename );
  $filename = wpcf7_antiscript_file_name( $filename );
  $filename = wp_unique_filename( $uploads_dir, $filename );

  $new_file = trailingslashit( $uploads_dir ) . $filename;

  if ( false === @move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $new_file ) ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'upload_failed' ) );
    return $result;
  }

  // Make sure the uploaded file is only readable for the owner process
  @chmod( $new_file, 0400 );

  if ( $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance() ) {
    $submission->add_uploaded_file( $name, $new_file );
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Paste this snippet in your functions.php file
append your required file types at the end
in line

```html
$file_type_pattern = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|odt|avi|ogg|m4a|mov|mp3|mp4|mpg|wav|wmv|ai|eps|tif';
```

and you are good to go...

Comment: Can you explain what this code is doing, or why you are suggesting this? Code-only answers are sometimes not real helpful.

Comment: this is the answer to the question, he is asking to extend Contact form 7 to send the file extentions not natively supported by Contact form 7. With this code you can extend the supported file extentions.

Comment: Interestingly... the above code appears almost verbatim in a publicly available WordPress Plugin. Sadly, no attribution appears in either this answer or the afore mentioned plugin. ~ come on people; we can do better than this!

Comment: Actually, accordingly to their documentation (https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/): 
"Contact Form 7 applies default restrictions for file type (...) when you do not set the filetypes". 
What means that if you set the file types, it will accept other file types rather than the ones wordpress accepts by default. I tested now and it worked with a .zip and a .rvt and both worked.